# how to align two labels and two textboxes without a gap in form-horizontal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I am pretty new to using Bootstrap, and have hit a brick wall when trying to have a label, a textbox, a label and a textbox on the same line without a big gap between, and so that the State TextBox and Zip TextBox line up with the other TextBoxes and I can't seem to get my Submit button the line up properly either..Here is a screenshot

[image: Some controls not lined up properly and there is a gap]

The markup for all this is

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <h4>Please add your information</h4>
        <hr />
        <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" />
        <div class="form-group form-horizontal col-md-8">
            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtName" Text="Name" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label"></asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtLastName" Text="Last Name" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label"></asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Address1" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label" Text="Address1"></asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Address1" CssClass="form-control" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Address2" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label" Text="Address2"></asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Address2" CssClass="form-control" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtCity" Text="City" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCity" CssClass="form-control" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtState" Text="State" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtState" CssClass="form-control" />
                </div>
                <asp:Label ID="lblZip" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtZip" Text="Zip" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtZip" CssClass="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ddCountry" Text="Country" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddCountry" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-2">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Send" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have had success using form-inline, but I like the looks of form-horizontal.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong

**EDIT**

Here is a screen shot of when I use form-inline, its aligned to the left and I can't figure out how to indent it.
[image: form-inline]

**EDIT 2**

This is how I am trying to get it to look.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `form-group` classes around each of your "rows", like this:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <h4>Please add your information</h4>
  <hr />
  <div class="form-horizontal col-md-8">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input id="Name" type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="LastName" class="col-md-4 control-label">Last Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input id="LastName" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="State" class="col-md-4 control-label">State</label>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="State" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <label for="Zip" class="col-md-4 control-label">Zip</label>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="Zip" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Country</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <select class="form-control"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

*Note:* I switched the ASP.NET server controls to their HTML counterparts. The Bootstrap class usage is what to take note of, you can obviously apply those to the server controls via the `CssClass` attribute as you did in your code.

Also, I made each "row" in your markup add up to 12 to fill the 8-unit container you are putting them into. This eliminates the need to have line breaks in your markup, as when Bootstrap gets to the 12th unit it will go to the next row.

---

**UPDATE**

To make the State and Zip entries behave more like you would like you will need to use the `form-inline` class on that "row" of information like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-inline">
    <label for="State" class="col-md-4 control-label">State</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input id="State" class="form-control" />
      <label for="Zip" class="control-label" 
             style="padding-left: 20px;">Zip</label>
      <input id="Zip" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Note* This creates a 4 unit area for the State label so it lines up with the other row's labels and then an 8-unit area for the remaining controls (State textbox, Zip label and Zip textbox). The `padding-left` style can be obviously be adjusted to a different value or unit (`em` or percentage) and pulled out into a CSS file instead of inline, but you get the idea.

**UPDATE 2**

Based upon the screenshot of the layout you want, try this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="State" class="col-md-4 control-label">State</label>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input id="State" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <label for="Zip" class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-1 control-label">Zip</label>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input id="Zip" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

*Note* This uses an offset to push the Zip label and consequently the Zip textbox to the right and makes the Zip label one unit wide.

To make the Send button align right, put it into a 12-unit row and pull the button to the right, like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Note* The `pull-right` class is part of the button markup.

Comment: Thanks, it looks a lot better things are lined up now, the only thing that is bothering me is the gap between the State textbox and the Zip label. Is there a way to shorten the gap between the two? I have done it using form-inline instead of form-horizontal, but then it aligns to the left of the window and I am not sure how to add space between the left side of the window to the first label, I apologize if I am not explaining properly

Comment: I'll edit and show a screen shot when I use form-inline instead, with form-inline I can't figure out how to move it over from the left side of the browser window

Comment: @Chris - not sure what you mean by right next to each other, could you update your question with a drawing of how you want the the state and ZIP labels/textboxes to be in relation to each other and themselves?

Comment: Just edited and added a screen shot..The screen shot is using form-inline, but using form-inline aligns it left. I chose form-horizontal because it indents the group.

Comment: @Chris - how much indention do you want for the Zip label? Can you post a screenshot of what layout you want?

Comment: @Chris - See UPDATE in my answer and if that gives you what you need.

Comment: I just edited and added a screen of how I am trying to get it to look.

Comment: Thank you sir, you have given me a lot of insight in using the grid system

Comment: @Chris - no problem, good luck to you. I highly recommend a site like Bootply which lets you paste your markup and play around with it, here is part of your markup that I verified on that site (http://www.bootply.com/4k7mNGpBJ4). The really cool part is you can share this with other people, if you wish or keep them private in your own account. Also, you do not need to create an account to use the site or save versions of changes you make.

Comment: Definitely going to check that site out. It'll help a lot when I have another question, will make it a lot easier on those providing assistance.

Answer (score 2):

So I think one of the issues is how your forms groups are nested.
Also you are using form-horizontal I think you mean to be using form-inline

Here is just some example code.

here is a quick mock up on codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doowyQ

```
<h4>add your information</h4>
<form>
  <div class="form-group col-md-8">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    <div class="form-inline">
      <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
</form>
```